# Getting "null" when selecting second or futher columns in Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

so I have e.g. the following XML file:

```
<root>
  <first>
    <a>textA</a>
  </first>
  <second>
    <b>textB</b>
  </second>
  <third>
    <c>textC</c>
  </third>
</root>
```

I load it into Spark through the DataBricks XML package, and everything looks good and loaded correctly.
When I try to select `first`or `first.a`, then I get the result correctly.

But if I try to get `second` or `second.b`, or `third` or `third.c`, then I get `null`.

I tried with a direct query, select function, everything, I don't know what the problem is.
The rowTag is root.
Any ideas?

**Update**: Never mind, apparently it was a bug in the spark-xml package. Thanks.

Comment: could you paste related code with xml loading here? it's difficult to check only with xml but without how you load that

Comment: I modified the post to say that it was a bug in the spark-xml package. Thanks anyways.